# Using \! for spacing in nomenclature

Tags: spacing, nomenclature, makeindex, nomencl

I have a symbol in my nomenclature that needs a negative thinspace command `\!` in the subscript. But whenever I try to do that in the nomenclature, it fails to compile. The error I get is:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6     \subitem
                 [{$V_{\
```

This is a MWE where the problem occurs:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

    \nomenclature[$V_{\infty}$]{$V_{\!\infty}$}{Freestream velocity}
    \printnomenclature[0.75in]

\end{document}
```

I compile this using `pdflatex example.tex`, then, `makeindex example.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o example.nls`, and then `pdflatex example.tex` again.

Any idea how to get it to compile with negative space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` character is used internally by MakeIndex, so you cannot use it directly. For normal exclamation marks you can [quote them with "](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130696/134574). This one, as it is a control character, you can rename it to use in the nomenclature:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

% Copying \! to \negspace
\let\negspace\!

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[$V_{\infty}$]{$V_{\negspace\infty}$}{Freestream velocity}
\printnomenclature[0.75in]

hello % some text to force output

\end{document}
```

Also, the optional argument to `\nomenclature` is a sorting key, you can usually omit it unless you want to override MakeIndex's sorting.

`\begin{advertisement}`

And you may also be interested in a [modification of the `nomencl` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432863/134574) I did to allow easy classification of the nomenclature :)

`\end{advertisement}`

Comment: Thanks! Also for pointing out the sorting thing. I just do it automatically, because I also have to use that for greek symbols, which makeindex does not sort correctly.